# RMarkdown + bibLaTeX; How to print bibliography?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, bibtex, biblatex

I am writing a thesis template according to very specific University rules, and RMarkdown won't let me include a page with the bibliography pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex with a regular .tex file

So far I have this:

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    template: formato-uchile.tex
    keep_tex: no
    citation_package: biblatex
  bibliography: bibliografia.bib
---
```

Here is the full document https://github.com/pachamaltese/template-tesis-uchile/blob/master/tesis-rmarkdown.Rmd

How can I include that bibliography page?

Comment: Just checking if you have read through this yet? https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html

Comment: Yes, I checked that and I cannot force to show the pages with the references

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to indent `bibliography` line in the YAML section.

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    template: formato-uchile.tex
    keep_tex: no
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: bibliografia.bib
biblio-style: path/to/your/style-file-without-file-extention
---
```

[As mentioned here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html#bibliography_placement), your bibliography will be shown in the end of the section. This is automatic, so you may need TeXing to change the order of the bibliography and appendices. If you want to do so, I highly recommend you to set `keep_tex: yes` so that you can get `.tex` file to edit.

Comment: Thanks! it works (throws 0 errors) but still refuses to print the references page. If I open the exported .tex with texmaker and do pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex, then it works with printed references page.